# perl - string compare failing while fetching a line from a file.

Tags: perl

my code,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;


my $codes=" ";
my $count=0;
my $str1="code1";
open (FILE, '/home/vpnuser/testFile.txt') or  die("Could not open the file.");

while($codes=<FILE>)
{
        print($codes);
        if($codes eq $str1)
        {       
                $count++;
        }
}         
print "$count";
```

the comparison always fails. my testFile.txt contains one simple line -  code1
when i have written a separate perl script where i have two strings declared in the script it self rather than getting it from a file, the eq operator works fine. but when i am getting it from a file, there is a problem. Pease help,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your file input if you don't want it to end in a return character.

```
while(my $codes = <FILE>)
{
    chomp $codes;
```

That is likely the reason why your string comparison is failing.

As on additional aside, kudus for including [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the the top of your script, like one should always do.

I'd like to recommend that you also include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) at the top as well when doing file processing.  It will automatically give you a detailed error message for doing many kinds of operations, such as opening a file, so you won't have to remember to include the error code `$!` or the filename in your `die` statement.

Comment: now it works , but @Miller, my doubt is, in the file if i have only one word "code1" and i dont press any "enter" there , then there will be no return character at the end rite?? in that case, it should work without the chomp rite?? but its not working without chomp

Comment: If your file definitively contained just a single word and no return character, then, yes, a `chomp` would be unnecessary in this case.  However, that is why `chomp` is such a useful function, since it will leave the string alone if it doesn't end with a input record separator.  Therefore, it doesn't hurt to use it, and almost always is advantageous to do so.